# Runtime.exec() command with utf-8 characters

Tags: java, encoding, runtime

I'm trying to execute Runtime.getRuntime().exec() command which contains polish characters. Command is cutted from the first polish letter. Instead of polish letter i'm getting "?".

How can I set correct encoding to exec this command properly?

Command which i'm using :
execCommand("php /home/script/url param1 param2 param3)

execCommand looks like :

```
private String execCommand(String command)
{
    String output="";
    try
    {
        Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
        try
        {
        proc.waitFor();
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e) 
        {
            output=e.getMessage();
        }
        while(read.ready())
        {
            output=read.readLine();
        }
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        output=e.getMessage();
    }

    return output;
}
```

Comment: Could you tell us more details? How is your command look like? How are you running it (via IDE or command line)? What is your OS (what language is it using)? What is encoding of your java files?

Comment: It's slackware 14. I'm running java app on server. Encoding in application and other functions is correct. I can operate on polish strings without any problems. It looks like it only affect exec() command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
String command = URLEncoder.encode("<your command>", "utf-8");
```

You could then try to run that via `Runtime.exec`

You could also check if your JDK actually supported:

```
Charset.forName("UTF-8")
```

If this fails for any reasons then there's probably something wrong/not configured in your JDK

Comment: I cant use URLEncoder i'm getting error : Unhandled exception type UnsupportedEncodingException. In other places in my app I can use polish characters so i'm sure that jdk is supporting utf-8.

Comment: Charset.forName("UTF-8") returning "UTF-8" so that's what we expect ?

Comment: Yes, thats fine.  It was just a check really.  Without being able to reproduce this myself I can only really offer one further suggestion - can you put the command you want to execute into an external script (.bat for windows, .sh perhaps for linux) and then in turn run that script via Runtime.exec? That way you dont have to encode anything in your actual program

Comment: That's right direction I can't execute this command via shell. I'm getting the same results, almost because now i'm not getting "?" at first occurrence of polish letters. I can use polish letters in shell but it seems that PHP is not parsing this in correct way. Now I know where to look for an answear. I'll let you know if i will find the solution ;)

Comment: Changing unix locale to pl_PL.utf8 solves the problem. Thank for your time Sean