# Java: Runtime.exec() and Unicode symbols on Windows: how to make it work with non-English letters?

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, unicode

## Intro

I am using **Runtime.exec()** to execute some external command and I am using parameters that contain **non-English characters**. I simply want to run something like this:
`python test.py шалом`

**It works correctly in cmd directly, but is incorrectly handled via** `Runtime.exec.getRuntime()("python test.py шалом")`

On Windows my external program fails due to unknown symbols passed to it.

I remember **similar issue** from early 2010s (!) - [JDK-4947220](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6927419), but I thought it is already fixed since Java core 1.6.

## **Environments:**

**OS:** Name    Microsoft Windows 10 Pro (Version 10.0.18362 Build 18362)

**Java:** jdk1.8.0_221

## Code

To understand the question - the best way is to use code snippet listed below:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class MainClass {
    private static void foo(String filename) {
        try {
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(
                            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(filename).getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            input.close();
        } catch (Exception e) { /* ... */ }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        foo("你好.bat 你好"); // ??
        foo("привет.bat привет"); // ??????
        foo("hi.bat hi"); // hi
    }
}
```

Where .bat file contains only simple `@echo %1` 
The output will be:

```
??
??????
hi
```

PS
 `System.out.println("привет")` - works fine and prints everything correctly

## **Questions are the following:**

1) Is this issue related to Utf-8 utf-16 formats?

2) How to fix this issue? I do not like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15394986/runtime-exec-command-with-utf-8-) as it looks like a very dangerous and ugly workaround.

3) Does anyone know why file names of batch file is not broken and this file can be found, but the argument gets broken? May be it is problem of `@echo`?

Comment: 1. What version of Windows are you running? 2. What codepage is your console window? 3. If you run `System.out.println("привет");` to print a hard-coded string directly to the console, what do you see?

Comment: The problem is that Windows and Java both internally use 16 bits characters (the Basic Multilingual Plane of unicode) but their interface only uses 8 bits, so they must agree of a common encoding.

Comment: Try `java MainClass x.txt >y.txt` as the console by default uses the local console's encoding, often single byte, and hence not Unicode capable. Also your InputStreamReader needs as extra parameter the encoding/charset of the file: `StandardCharsets.UTF_8`.

Comment: I guess there is no sense to answer your questions, as @edwgiz is saying that it is a windows bug, but anyway - I have updated the info in the post

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, issue is related with UTF. Theoretically a setting 65001 codepage for `cmd` that executes the bat files should solve the issue (along with setting UTF-8 charset as default at the Java side)
2. Unfortunately there a bug in Windows mentioning here [Java, Unicode, UTF-8, and Windows Command Prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11927518/java-unicode-utf-8-and-windows-command-prompt)
3. So there's no simple and complete solution. What it's possible to do is to set the same default language-specific encoding, like cp1251 Cyrillic, for both `java` and `cmd`. Not all languages are well reflected in the windows encodings, for example Chinese is one of them.

If there's some non-technical restriction on the windows system to change default encoding to the language-specific one for all `cmd` processes, the java code will be more complicated. At beginning new cmd process have to be created and to its stdin/stdout streams should be attached reader with UTF-16LE (for `cmd /U' process) and writer with CP1251 from different threads. First command sending to stdin from java should be 'chcp 1251' and second is the name of bat-file with its parameters.

Complete solution still may use UTF-16LE for reading of cmd output but to pass a text in, other universal encoding should be used, for example base64, which again leads to increasing complexity

Comment: How we can live with that? May be someone has reported that to guys from Micro any link to the bug?

Comment: May be there's some backward compatibility doesn't allow to fix the bug for the years,
we can only come up with some workarounds, one of them I've just suggested