# How to properly scan standart input text data?

Tags: java, user-input

I am trying to scan text data from standart input. However encodig does not work properly. For example if i provide following characters:

```
óś
```

This is what i receive:

```
data: '??'
```

The code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, UnknownHostException, IOException {
    Charset ENCODING = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in, ENCODING);

    for (;;) {
        String line = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("data: '" + line + "'");
    }
}
```

Comment: Small recommendation. Instead of using the blank `for(;;)` loop, you may want to consider using `while(in.hasNextLine())` so it will only run for as long as the scanner has values. Also, don't forget to close your scanner with `in.close();` after your loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The encoding of `cmd` or `bash` should be the same with the encoding in java. In what OS the java is run? If you use windows there's some restriction regarding UTF-8,
details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59989494/2553521

Answer (score 0):

Following program worked for me.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, Exception {
        Charset ENCODING = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in, String.valueOf(ENCODING));

        for (;;) {
            String line = in.nextLine();
            System.out.println("data: '" + line + "'");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This did not change anything from my solution.